# PHP DOMDocument not being able to create <image></image>-tag

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use DOMDocument in PHP to create an XML-document containing an element formated like this:

```
    <image>
        <url>
              http://webpage.com/images/img.jpg
        </url>
    </image>
```

The problem is that it gets converted to this:

```
    <img>
    <url><img></url>
```

Does it have something to do with the image tag name being reserved, since it defaults to a normal HTML tag.

My current code snippet for this:

```
    $frag = $domtree->createDocumentFragment();
    $frag->appendXML('<image>\n<url></url></image>');
    $listing->appendChild($frag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're source is incomplete. The creation of the document object and the `$listing` node is missing and here is no output. Fixing that it works fine:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();

$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<image>\n<url>http://webpage.com/images/img.jpg</url></image>');
$document->appendChild($fragment);

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<image>\n<url>http://webpage.com/images/img.jpg</url></image>
```

PHP will not recognize `\n` as a linefeed inside a single quoted string. It only supports that in double quoted strings.

Creating XML from fragments is fine, but most of the time you might want to create the
nodes directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild($image = $document->createElement('image'));
$image->appendChild($url = $document->createElement('url'));
$url->appendChild($document->createTextNode('http://webpage.com/images/img.jpg'));

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<image><url>http://webpage.com/images/img.jpg</url></image>
```